# validate regex with alpha numerics and special characters

Tags: regex

Trying to get this regex working:

```
^([a-zA-Z]+)([a-zA-Z0-9\.\(\)]*){1,10}$
```

`([a-zA-Z]+)`
The starting character must be `a-z` or `A-Z`, followed by additional chars in the same range, that's working.

`([a-zA-Z0-9\.\(\)]*)`
Any number of additional characters can be `a-z`, `A-Z`, or `.` `(` `)`, and that's working.

Which leaves `{1,10}` to restrict the length to no more than 10 characters, mininimum of 1 char; that part is not working. I tried using different parentheses combinations, but could not get the length to validate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
^[A-Za-z][a-zA-Z0-9.()\s-]{0,9}$
```

**Updated** to include support for whitespace and `-`

You can't use the `{x,x}` range class for multiple capture groups; it works on a single character or character class only.

Since you know you want it to be at least 1 char, `[A-Za-z]` (at the beginning of the line with `^`) already requires that; the rest, you now can allow 0 or 9 times with `{0,9}`, completing the statement with the end line `$`.

See [`Live demo`](http://regex101.com/r/oJ3cH7)

Comment: I thought `.` had to be escaped? +1 on regex101!

Comment: @raffian common misconception ;) `.` does not need to be escaped in a character class, nor does `-` so long as it's not used to define a range of characters.

Comment: @r3mus Trying to add `-` and whitespace support to your example using `^[A-Za-z][a-zA-Z0-9-.\(\)\s]{0,9}$`, but it's throwing off the parser.

Comment: `^[A-Za-z][a-zA-Z0-9.()\s-]{0,9}$`

Comment: @hwnd that allows for numerics as the first character, which must be `a-z or `A-Z`

Comment: @r3mus the last update is working, ty, so what special chars, aside from whitespace, have to be escaped? the chars you're not escaping contradict what I've read, nevertheless, it's working, and I'd rather not escape anyway :-)

Comment: @raffian as hwnd pointed out, only   \[ \] \ and ^  I believe. You can of course escape more than that though, it just looks ugly.

Comment: @hwnd perhaps regex101 was misleading me, it was allowing numerics when I tested your regex, my apologies, ive never used it, seems to be ok after refreshing :-)

Comment: Read [Metacharacters Inside Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Comment: I was just trying to help you out =)